# Android: How to disable "dbopen(): path = ..."

Tags: android, database, debugging, sqlite, logging

When my application opens a SQLite database, a message is written to the log similar to the following:

```
dbopen(): path = /data/data/myApp/databases/myDb.s3db
```

Although I know that people with an unrooted phone will not be able to access that part of the system, I don't particularly like that the path is displayed for anyone to see who might glance at the logs. Plus, people with a rooted phone COULD access the database and it may contain sensitive information.

I know, I know, I should encrypt sensitive data - and I do. The question remains, however, does anyone know how to disable that log message? I haven't yet found a way.

I thank all of you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure why you're worried about if someone with root, because that won't stop ANYONE with root (disabling the log). It's not hard to just CD into your folder, I have hacked many games in this way.

Just use data structures and save to a file...To my best knowledge you can't disable SQLite logging.